# How to calculate percentage of cells in data frame that start with sequence in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

I have data that looks like:

```
Row 1     Row 2     Row 3     Row 4     Row 5     Row 6     Row7
abc89     abc62     67        abc513    abc512    abc81     abc10
abc6      pop       abc11     abc4      giant     13        abc15
abc90     abc16     abc123    abc33     abc22     abc08     9
111       abc15     abc72     abc36     abc57     abc9      abc55
```

I would like to calculate the percentage of cells in the data frame that begin with "abc". For example: there are 28 total cells here. This can be gotten by `prod(dim(df))`. So I need the # of cells that start with "abc" and then divide it by `prod(dim(df))`. Here the answer would be 0.785. how can this be done in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use:

```
> mean(grepl("^abc",unlist(dat)))
[1] 0.7857143
```

Using `mean` means you don't have to get the numerator and denominator yourself separately. `grepl` is the logical version of `grep`--it returns `TRUE` whenever `"^abc"` (i.e., a string beginning with `abc`) is found. [Recall](http://www.randomservices.org/random/interval/Bernoulli.html) that the average of a Bernoulli vector is the percentage of successes.

If you wanted to do this by row or by column you'd use `apply`, e.g. `apply(dat,1,function(x)mean(grepl("^abc",x)))` to get the row-wise means.

Comment: Or another option is `mean(substr(as.matrix(dat),1,3)=='abc')`

Comment: How could I make a histogram of row.counts for things starting with "abc"?

Comment: @Evan I think that is grounds for a new question (you can reference this question if you'd like); I suggest you search around first, though, as this sounds like a pretty common operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` to search for the pattern of interest (a string starting with "abc"):

```
length(grep("^abc", as.character(unlist(dat)))) / prod(dim(dat))
# [1] 0.7857143
```

You can get row counts with:

```
(row.counts <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) length(grep("^abc", as.character(x)))))
# [1] 6 4 6 6
```

Data:

```
dat = read.table(text="Row1     Row2     Row3     Row4     Row5     Row6     Row7
 abc89     abc62     67        abc513    abc512    abc81     abc10
 abc6      pop       abc11     abc4      giant     13        abc15
 abc90     abc16     abc123    abc33     abc22     abc08     9
 111       abc15     abc72     abc36     abc57     abc9      abc55", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: How could I make a histogram of row.counts of things starting with "abc"?

Comment: @Evan updated to compute counts by row; you would just do `hist(row.counts)`.