# How to calculate row counts in dataframe of specific cells in R

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

I asked a similar question before here: [How to calculate percentage of cells in data frame that start with sequence in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775978/how-to-calculate-percentage-of-cells-in-data-frame-that-start-with-sequence-in-r)

I'll copy some of it over to ask the new question.

I have data that looks like:

```
Set_1     Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5     Set_6     Set_7
abc89     abc62     67        abc513    abc512    abc81     abc10
abc6      pop       abc11     abc4      giant     13        abc15
abc90     abc16     abc123    abc33     abc22     abc08     9
111       abc15     abc72     abc36     abc57     abc9      abc55
```

I would like to make a histogram of row counts. I would only like to count the cells that start with "abc". So Row 1 would have 6 cells. Row 2 has 4 cells. Row 3 has 6 cells, etc. I would like to make a histogram of this. How can this be done in R? Currently my data is in a data.frame.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, perhaps because you have the columns labeled as rows.

Comment: @Webb, that was dumb of me. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 2):

You can count the number of entries starting with "abc" in each row with

```
y <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(grepl("^abc", x)))
#> y 
#[1] 6 4 6 6
```

This result could be plotted in a histogram with

```
hist(y, breaks=c(1:max(y)), main = "Frequency of 'abc' entries", col="lightblue")
```

[image]

If you prefer a graphical representation of the value of "abc" counts for each row, you could use `barplot()` instead of `hist()`:

```
barplot(y, main = "Number of 'abc' entries in each row",col="lightblue")
```

[image]

**data**

```
text <- "Set_1     Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5     Set_6     Set_7
abc89     abc62     67        abc513    abc512    abc81     abc10  
abc6      pop       abc11     abc4      giant     13        abc15
abc90     abc16     abc123    abc33     abc22     abc08     9
111       abc15     abc72     abc36     abc57     abc9      abc55"
df <- read.table(text=text, header=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyr`, `dplyr` and base R `hist`

```
x <- data.frame(Set_1 = c("abc89", "abc6", "abc90", 111), 
            Set_2 = c("abc62", "pop", "a16", "abc15"), 
            Set_3 = c(67, "abc11", "abc123", "abc72"), 
            Set_4 = c("abc513", "abc4", "abc33", "abc36"),      stringsAsFactors=F)

require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)

x %>% 
  gather(Set, val) %>%
  group_by(Set) %>%
  summarise(count=sum(grepl("^abc", val))) %>%
  .$count %>%
  hist
```

Sorry, I cannot attach the image output.